# Python dictionary storing values incorrectly?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, dictionary, openpyxl

I'm using Python's openpyxl package to read contents from an excel file and I'm storing cell values and their parent values in a dictionary. Cells that are not bold are considered 'Tasks' and cells that are bold are considered 'Summaries'.

Here is an example of an Excel file I'm trying to read:
[image: example excel file]

For each task, I want to store the task name and its summaries (as a list) in a dictionary. For example, in the example excel file, Task 4 would be stored with the name 'Task 4' and its summaries would be ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']. I calculate the nested parent summaries based on the leading spaces.

My issue is that in the while loop, the summaries list is calculating correctly whereas when I print all the task names and summaries in my dictionary, the summaries are wrong.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

tasks = {}

task_summaries = []
curr_left_spaces = -1

i = 2
current_cell = sheet[f'A{i}']

while current_cell.value:
    if current_cell.font.bold:
        # calculate number of leading spaces to determine nesting level
        left_spaces = num_left_spaces(current_cell.value) 
        curr_summary = current_cell.value.strip()

        if left_spaces > curr_left_spaces:
            task_summaries.append(curr_summary)
            curr_left_spaces = left_spaces
        elif left_spaces < curr_left_spaces:
            task_summaries = [curr_summary]
            curr_left_spaces = left_spaces
        else:
            assert (left_spaces == curr_left_spaces)
            task_summaries.pop()
            task_summaries.append(curr_summary)

    else:
        task_name = current_cell.value.strip() 

        # prints correct task_summaries list here
        print(task_name, task_summaries) 

        tasks[task_name] = task_summaries

    i += 1
    current_cell = self.sheet[f'A{i}']


for name, summary in tasks.items():
    print(name, summary) # summary is incorrect here
```

Expected results:

```
Task 1 ['First Summary']
Task 2 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 1']
Task 3 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 1']
Task 4 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']
Task 5 ['Second Summary']
Task 6 ['Second Summary']
Task 1 ['First Summary']
Task 2 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 1']
Task 3 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 1']
Task 4 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']
Task 5 ['Second Summary']
Task 6 ['Second Summary']
```

Actual results:

```
Task 1 ['First Summary']
Task 2 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 1']
Task 3 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 1']
Task 4 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']
Task 5 ['Second Summary']
Task 6 ['Second Summary']
Task 1 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']
Task 2 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']
Task 3 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']
Task 4 ['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']
Task 5 ['Second Summary']
Task 6 ['Second Summary']
```

Comment: Why is the set printed twice?

Comment: @Tomerikoo The set is printed twice because I printed it once in the while loop (to show that the summaries list is being calculated correctly) and then it is printed once more outside the while loop (to show that somehow, after the while loop is complete, the dictionary has stored the summaries list incorrectly).

Comment: Right! tottally missed that sorry :)

Comment: I am guessing that this is beacuse you are using the same `task_summaries` list for all entries. So when you're printing in the loop it prints fine, but when you add it to the dict it all references the same object. Try replacing this `tasks[task_name] = task_summaries` with `tasks[task_name] = [x for x in task_summaries]` I have a feeling it will solve your problem

Comment: @Tomerikoo That solved it! Thanks so much. :)

Comment: As a side note, if you are already using `openpyxl`, you should take advantage of its API and use `iter_rows` instead of the `while` loop. read in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the same `task_summaries` list for all entries and adding the new tasks to the dict with their values referencing to that same list.

So in the end all entries' values are the list `['First Summary', 'Nested Summary 2']`, and only then, at task 5, you do `task_summaries = [curr_summary]` which creates a new object for `task_summaries` and now the last two tasks are referencing that same list.

What you need to do is give each entry a new list, so change this line:

```py
tasks[task_name] = task_summaries
```

to:

```py
tasks[task_name] = list(task_summaries)
```

A simpler example to demonstrate:

```py
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = l   #  'a' gets a reference to l
>>> l[0] = 3     # so that changes 'a's value too
>>> print(l)
[3, 2]
>>> print(d)
{'a', [3, 2]}

>>> d['a'] = list(l)  # now 'a' gets a new copy of l
>>> l[0] = 4          # so that shouldn't affect him
>>> print(l)
[4, 2]
>>> print(d)
{'a', [3, 2]}
```